# Grails - 'in' node in Criteria query - groovy.lang.IntRange cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: grails, casting, range, criteria

I have an `Integer rankOnHighlights` property in my `Project` domain class. 
I want to query all projects that have a `rankOnHighlights` property between 1 and 45.

For this, I issue the following Criteria query:

```
Project.withCriteria {
        'in' "rankOnHighlights",[1..45]
        maxResults 45
        order "rankOnHighlights", "desc"
    }
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
groovy.lang.IntRange cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I have tried various different writings but to no avail. 
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work, but it should since it's similar to an example in the docs - http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html - you should create an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

This does work however:

```
between "rankOnHighlights", 1, 45
```

**Edit**:
I figured out what's happening, it should be

```
'in' "rankOnHighlights", (1..45)
```

but I'd still use `between` since `in` generates bad SQL (and if the range is wide enough it can be too large for the database query parser):

```
...
where
    this_.rank_on_highlights in (
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )
...
```